# Page editing options unavailable for Admin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I am the admin of a site and created few pages. It asked me to publish the pages. I've done it however, there is no page options/edit button to edit the page.

This appears on home page (editing page/create a new page) but not on the pages I've created. Is this due to permission issues? Do I have to unlock/open the pages? How do I do this?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be in the menu on top right corner of the page

[image]